# Plotting response variables and using the lm function

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot the response variables chl, SST and upwelling as a function of explanatory variable
latitude on a single figure. Because these response variables have different ranges, I
will have to plot each one on a separate panel.
this is the data:

d1 <- read.csv("http://www.northeastern.edu/synchrony/stats/data/assn4_dataset1.csv")

Also I need to use lm function to fit a multiple regression model that relates chl to SST, upwelling,
and latitude (from the same data).

Finally, Fit a multiple regression that relates chl to SST and upwelling only.

So far to plot the variables I have:

plot(table(d1$chl, d1$SST)

lm.fit <- (d1)

I'm a beginner and uber confused

Comment: It's an optional practice problem my professor gave us. It's more advanced stuff we're going to learn later on but he handed it out in case some of us want to learn more about the more complex aspects/functions/syntax of R

Answer (score 0):

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))                            # Split plot window in 2 row and 2 col
plot(chl ~ latitude, data=d1, type="l")      # type="p" for points
plot(sst ~ latitude, data=d1, type="l")      # type="b" for points and line
plot(upwelling ~ latitude, data=d1, type="l")

myreg <- lm(upwelling ~ latitude, data=d1)
abline(myreg, col="blue")
summary(myreg)                               # Sum up results
    # See also predict(), coefficients(), confint(), ... ...

plot(myreg)                                  # To plot residuals etc...
```